# How do I make the options menu popup after an event?

Tags: android

I am trying to make an options menu popup after I drag and drop a marker on a map. In my map activitity I have this optionsmenu created:

```
  @Override 
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
  menu
   .add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST+1,Menu.NONE, "Use Point?");
   //.setIcon(R.drawable.androidmarker);
  menu
    .add(Menu.NONE,Menu.FIRST+2,Menu.NONE,"Cancel");
    //.setIcon(R.drawable.androidmarker);

  return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));

  }
```

Is there a way I can execute this without pressing the menu button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think calling openOptionsMenu() will do what you want: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29